# Python cd in a folder without library

Tags: python, import, directory, operating-system, cd

I have this script:

```
target = input("Choose your target: ")
... etc ...
```

When script runs, it creates a folder with target's value and inside it another .json file  .

For example if target = Test , then I want to read:
/Test/Test.json

I have found some commands to do it,but I need os library.

Is there any way to do it without library?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the `os` module? It comes with Python; you don't need to do any extra work to use it.

Comment: I have the last part which edits the file: ///
json_str = open(target + ".json", 'r').read() ///
But I need to get in the folder first

Comment: @chepner It's a project that I am not allowed to use libraries

Comment: If the parent dir is also named identically, why not simply `open('/{0}/{0}.json'.format(target))`?

Comment: Does the file exist? Are you sure you don't need `{0}/{0}.json` instead (no leading `/`)?

Comment: Folder and file exists. I think the problem is cause of the name has a dot. Also why format is target? Shouldn't be json?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/1pA5tBS.png

Comment: you have to at least  remove  `/` at the beginning because it search in main folder not in `Askhsh_6`. But if code works in different folder then `Askhsh_6` ( see `os.getcwd()`) then you may need full path

Comment: Yeah! ///
Indeed the correct command is open('{0}/{0}.json'.format(target)). Thanks for your help :)